# Is there a way to pipe input video into ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:0" -vf "crop=1920:1080:0:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -r 30 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://RTMP_SERVER:RTMP_PORT/STREAM_KEY`

Hello guys, the above command works pretty well. It records the audio/video of the computer. But what I want to do is pipe a repeating video or image(png/jpeg/gif), so that there is no live video feed from the computer, but just the image on the stream with the audio.

How would you go about doing this?

Also, if you know any programming interfaces that can do this same thing, please give suggestions. Because I would rather not use a CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this by using `-loop` and some `-map`:ing. I can't test with avfoundation myself but something like this works for me:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i file_to_take_audio_from.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:0:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -map 0:v -map 1:a output.mp4
```

Replace `-i file_to_take_audio_from.mp4` with `-f avfoundation -i "1:0"` and `output.mp4` with `-f flv rtmp://RTMP_SERVER:RTMP_PORT/STREAM_KEY`.

Also you might be able to skip `-vf` if the image has correct resolution.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use `none` or no value at all (`:0`) for the video device index and provide a secondary input:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i :0 -i image.png ...
```

There's a `loop` option for images such as animated GIFs and `-stream_loop` for input streams.

You can use the FFmpeg APIs directly instead of CLI.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how I would do something like this in the API?

Comment: There are examples for reading, encoding, muxing and so on in the `doc/examples` directory of the ffmpeg source package.